# Testing Token with Uniswap liquidity provisioning using hardhat

Tags: testing, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm attempting to fork Safemoon (or really NotSafeMoon), and use it as a vehicle to learn smart contract development. (I've got a substantial amount of what you might call "Web 2.0" dev experience).

So say I have something like so in my constructor:

```
constructor () {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);       // binance PANCAKE V2
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
```

When I run my tests with `npx hardhat test` I get the following failure:

```
Compilation finished successfully


  TestToken contract
    Deployment
      1) "before each" hook for "Has the right name"


  0 passing (807ms)
  1 failing

  1) TestToken contract
       "before each" hook for "Has the right name":
     Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
```

Now, this does make perfect sense, after all I am attempting to call the Pancakeswap v2 router contract. How do I get around this limitation? Is there a way to inject the contract address for the router as an environment variable perhaps? Is there a mock constructor for the UniswapRouter I can be using? Generally, how is this sort of thing done in a way that remains testable (and how is it therefore tested) with smart contract development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hardhat test deploys the contracts to the hardhat local network (by default). This local network only has few pre-funded and unlocked accounts, but there are no smart contracts deployed. Including the PancakeSwap v2 Router ([0x10ED43...](https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E#code)).

---

Instead of deploying and configuring local copy of the router contract, as well as all of its dependencies, you can create a new hardhat network forked from the production BSC.

https://hardhat.org/guides/mainnet-forking.html

This will run a local network with the Router contract available, but your actions will only effect the local network (not the mainnet).

Comment: Hardhat suggest using Alchemy but it doesn't support BSC mainnet currently.